# Cant get php to work inside shortcode content

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

I tried several solutions from looking at similar questions within the site but it won't work me. =( Please help.

This is an excerpt from my original code:

```
<form action="" method="get">
<input type="text" name="search" value="">
<input type="submit" value="Search">
<?php echo do_shortcode('[expand]
<input type="checkbox" name="title" <?php if(isset($_GET['title'])) echo "checked='checked'"; ?>>
    <label for="ti">Title</label></td>
[/expand]'); ?>
</form>
```

Basically, I want my checkboxes to remain checked, if they were checked before hitting submit. Unfortunately, it's been hours and I can't get the php to work inside the shortcode.

Please help.

Comment: Do you need to open <?php again when you are once in it, in your do_shortcode func?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your can try this,

```
<form action="" method="GET">
    <input type="text" name="search" value="">
    <input type="submit" value="Search">
    <?php 
     $check=isset($_GET['title']) ? "checked='checked'" : '';
     echo do_shortcode('[expand]
     <input type="checkbox" name="title" '.$check.' ><label for="ti">Title</label></td>
     <input type="submit" value="Search">
     [/expand]'); 
    ?>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't. The php code in your string is no PHP code. You'd have to detect the parts that are actually PHP, and evaluate them.

Create the string that you want to embed in `[expand]` tags before you pass it to the `do_shortcode()` function.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of >
    Title
[/expand]'); ?>

Simply do

```
<?php
$state = isset($_GET['title'])?"checked='checked'":"";
$expand = "[expand]
<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"title\" ".$state. " >";
echo do_shortcode($expand);?>
```